# Reset Gitlab 2FA with existing Public Key

Tags: gitlab, two-factor-authentication

our company has a Gitlab account secured with 2FA. With the previous developer, the authentication device and the recovery codes have gone. Now I have only found a file with a public SSH key in the cloud. How can I reset 2FA using this public key?

Regards

I already tried ssh git@gitlab.com 2fa_recovery_codes (but dont think I got this right)

Output:
"The authentification of host 'gitlab.com (...)' cant be established. ...key fingerprint is SHA256:...
This key is not known by ay other names
Are you sure you want to continue conneting (yes/no[fingerprint]?

Yes

Warning: permanently added 'gitlab.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.

Comment: I would contact gitlab support. I doubt you can recover it with a *public* key

Comment: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/i-lost-my-totp-key-and-recovery-code/42320